# Removing two single quotes from data

Tags: sql, oracle

I somehow managed to get a parameter like data 'YYYYMMDD' data from ODI. I cannot manually change single quotes because they are used for filters as the given form in ODI and not accesible without function output.

I can transform it to 'data 'YYYYMMDD' data' something similar to string form to use replace function or something else but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT REPLACE('data 'YYYYMMDD' data','''','''''') from dual;
```

two single quotes in the string throws error.

```
needed output: 'data ''YYYYMMDD'' data'
```

I really appreciate any example or tips.

Comment: Why do you need to transform it at all?

Comment: @Alex Poole I needed to insert all of my filters to a table. I'm getting values from ODI itself and needed to transform it to string in order to insert it.

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE()` function is not needed, just put doubled single quotes for each needed single quotes , *except for the first and the last quotes* such as

```
SELECT 'data ''''YYYYMMDD'''' data' 
  FROM dual;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=80d8111aef7009d966685238d4683d7c)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I edited my question, it seemed like misunderstandable. I cannot manually change single quotes because they are used in ODI tool as filters and that's the data I got from getFilterList() function from ODI to list my filters in every interface. I need to transform it to string to insert it my filters_log_table. Again, thanks for your time. 

Comment: Hi @FANTE , you're welcome. Are you sure that the parts represented by `data` should be literal ? Perhaps you need simple concatenation such as `data||'YYYYMMDD'||data`, don't you?

Comment: example filter is = TRUNC(CROSSPORT.DWH_VALID_FROM (+))>=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-2,'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYYMMDD') AND EVNT.DWH_STATUS (+)=1
It is whole output of the function so it's not separatable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your example isn't with the `replace()` itself, its with how you are supplying the initial string value. That has single quotes in, so you need to escape those:

```
SELECT REPLACE('data ''YYYYMMDD'' data','''','''''') from dual;
```

```
| REPLACE('DATA''YYYYMMDD''DATA','''','''''') |
| :------------------------------------------ |
| data ''YYYYMMDD'' data                      |
```

It sounds like you're getting the initial string passed in, so you don't need to worry about that. Although it isn't clear why you need to manipulate it at all.

You could also use the alternative quoting mechanism, at least for the initial string; it's longer in this case if applied to the second and third arguments as well, but can be used for all of them:

```
SELECT REPLACE(q'^data 'YYYYMMDD' data^',q'^'^',q'^''^') from dual;
```

```
| REPLACE(Q'^DATA'YYYYMMDD'DATA^',Q'^'^',Q'^''^') |
| :---------------------------------------------- |
| data ''YYYYMMDD'' data                          |
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b271a8bd790f5d1d54dc308181c4eb12)